# Is it possible to host a WCF service using Mono's XSP Web server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, mono, xsp

I have made a very simple Asp.net web site with a WCF service - "Person.svc" - that runs fine when hosted on Asp.Net development server(visual web developer 2010), but if I host on Mono's XSP 2 and access some parse error is thrown. Can WCF services live inside a XSP Web site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run a modern version of Mono.   2.6 had some initial support, but you really want to be using our trunk release as WCF there is a lot more complete.

If you have bug reports, you should report those to:

http://mono-project.com/Bugs

With a sample test case that we can use to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to run a WCF service on mono-2.6.7 on Ubuntu. Now I'm trying to migrate 2.8.2 and I'm having trouble.

(I asked [Creating WCF services in mono 2.8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001350/creating-wcf-services-in-mono-2-8-2) question)

Please post the "some parse error is thrown.".

Comment: I'm having the same problems on mono 2.10.1 which is very frustrating:)