# Creating WCF services in mono 2.8.2

Tags: wcf, mono

I had mono-2.6.7 installed and and a WCF service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
             <behavior name="RestB"><webHttp/></behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Rest">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="RestB" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Rest" />
      </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

It worked.

I wanted to use multiple endpoints and I kept getting errors as soon as I specified the address, so I decided to try mono 2.8.2. After installing 2.8.2 (after adding serviceBehavior which mono complained about) I started getting:

```
"HttpListenerContext does not match any of the registered channels"
System.InvalidOperationException: HttpListenerContext does not match any of the registered channels
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http.HttpListenerManager.ProcessNewContext (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http.HttpContextInfo ctxi) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SvcHttpHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+c__Iterator2.MoveNext () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in :0
```

when trying to access urls which worked in mono-2.6.7.

I tried with both mod-mono-server2 and mod-mono-server4.

I tried to look up this problem but I couldn't find anything.

Could someone show me a working example of a WCF service in mono-2.8.2 or mono-2.6.7 configuration with multiple endpoints?

UPDATE: After reverting to mono-2.6.7 the my service 'Rest' shown above works again.

Thanks in advance gurus

Thanks
Tymek

Comment: Ok the problem (affecting 2.10 as well) is that UriTemplate/{var1}/{var2} don't work in 2.8 and 2.10.1. I substituted them with UriTemplate?x={var1}&y={var2}. Not ideal, but will do for me for now.

Comment: sorry, can you explain how have configured your envirment and where you have changed the uritemplate. I have problem to running a wcf under mod_mono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (affecting 2.10 as well) is that UriTemplate/{var1}/{var2} don't work in 2.8 and 2.10.1. I substituted them with UriTemplate?x={var1}&y={var2}. Not ideal, but will do for me for now.

Comment: To consume parameters from the query string, you don't need to specify a UriTemplate if you define a WCF method like: `MyResponseClass MyRequestMethod (string x, string y)`.  Did you ever get the parameters in the Uri the way you wanted?

Comment: If I remember correctly it was Mono specific issue and Mono has changed significantly. I'd say that query string solution was good enough and I don't remember trying more.

Answer (score 0):

The last question was really old and the issue still happening in mono 2.10. Fortunately, there is a new project to bring WCF to Linux.

The new libraries are located here

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf

I'm going to try them in Ubuntu and I will post an update about it.

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/Documentation/building/unix-instructions.md